# how to read data from a plist saved in document directory and display that as pdf in a new view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

So I save user input data in a `plist` in my document directory. data is consist of a few strings. such as text and image. the user inputs the data in a add view through textfields and the image through the camera or photo album.

I use the following for saving the data in add view controller:

```
// Name for the image
    NSString *imageName;

    if (self.image) {
        // Create a unique name for the image by generating a UUID, converting it to
        // a string, and appending the .jpg extension.
        CFUUIDRef imageUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
        imageName = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, imageUUID));
        CFRelease(imageUUID);
        imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];

        // Lookup the URL for the Documents folder
        NSURL *imageFileURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask][0];
        // Append the file name to create the complete URL for saving the image.
        imageFileURL = [imageFileURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:imageName isDirectory:NO];

        // Convert the image to JPG format and write the data to disk at the above URL.
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1.0f) writeToURL:imageFileURL atomically:YES];
    } else {
        // If there is no image, we must make sure imageName is not nil.
        imageName = @"";
    }
#define PLIST_NAME @"Data.plist"
    [self createPlistCopyInDocuments:PLIST_NAME];
    NSString *filePath = [self plistFileDocumentPath:PLIST_NAME];
    NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSDictionary *data = @{@"city":self.name,@"state":self.stateTextField.text,@"cityPrice":self.priceTextField.text,@"cityText":self.cityDescription.text, @"cityImage": imageName};
    [dataArray addObject:data];
    [dataArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

then i add the following method for the document path:

```
- (NSString *)plistFileDocumentPath:(NSString *)plistName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistName];
    return writablePath;
}

- (void)createPlistCopyInDocuments:(NSString *)plistName
{
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *plistFilePath = [self plistFileDocumentPath:plistName];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:plistFilePath];

    if (success) {
        return;
    }

    // The writable file does not exist, so copy from the bundle to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistName];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:plistFilePath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

then in my tableview controller i read the data and display that as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSString *filePath = [self plistFileDocumentPath:@"Data.plist"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL exist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
    if (!exist) {
        return;
    }
    NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    content = dataArray;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSString *)plistFileDocumentPath:(NSString *)plistName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistName];
    return writablePath;
}
```

i do have the plist in view did load as follows:

```
content = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

i also can display all the info properly in my detail view. i created a new view in order to display the data saved in the plist as a pdf file. i am able to retrieve the data from a existing plist in my directory but i can't convert that code to read the data from my saved plist.

this is how i create the pdf from that plist.

```
    - (IBAction)pdfPressed:(id)sender {


    // create some sample data. In a real application, this would come from the database or an API.
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sampleData" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary* data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray* students = [data objectForKey:@"Students"];

    // get a temprorary filename for this PDF
    path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    self.pdfFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.pdf", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] ]];

    // Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
    // This default is spelled out in the iOS documentation for UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(self.pdfFilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    // get the context reference so we can render to it.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    int currentPage = 0;

    // maximum height and width of the content on the page, byt taking margins into account.
    CGFloat maxWidth = kDefaultPageWidth - kMargin * 2;
    CGFloat maxHeight = kDefaultPageHeight - kMargin * 2;

    // we're going to cap the name of the class to using half of the horizontal page, which is why we're dividing by 2
    CGFloat classNameMaxWidth = maxWidth / 2;

    // the max width of the grade is also half, minus the margin
    CGFloat gradeMaxWidth = (maxWidth / 2) - kColumnMargin;


    // only create the fonts once since it is a somewhat expensive operation
    UIFont* studentNameFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    UIFont* classFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

    CGFloat currentPageY = 0;

    // iterate through out students, adding to the pdf each time.
    for (NSDictionary* student in students)
    {
        // every student gets their own page
        // Mark the beginning of a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);
        currentPageY = kMargin;

        // draw the student's name at the top of the page.
        NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                          [student objectForKey:@"FirstName"],
                          [student objectForKey:@"LastName"]];

        CGSize size = [name sizeWithFont:studentNameFont forWidth:maxWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [name drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(kMargin, currentPageY) forWidth:maxWidth withFont:studentNameFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        currentPageY += size.height;

        // draw a one pixel line under the student's name
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, kMargin, currentPageY);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, kDefaultPageWidth - kMargin, currentPageY);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        // iterate through the list of classes and add these to the PDF.
        NSArray* classes = [student objectForKey:@"Classes"];
        for(NSDictionary* class in classes)
        {
            NSString* className = [class objectForKey:@"Name"];
            NSString* grade = [class objectForKey:@"Grade"];

            // before we render any text to the PDF, we need to measure it, so we'll know where to render the
            // next line.
            size = [className sizeWithFont:classFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(classNameMaxWidth, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

            // if the current text would render beyond the bounds of the page,
            // start a new page and render it there instead
            if (size.height + currentPageY > maxHeight) {
                // create a new page and reset the current page's Y value
                UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);
                currentPageY = kMargin;
            }

            // render the text
            [className drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin, currentPageY, classNameMaxWidth, maxHeight) withFont:classFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

            // print the grade to the right of the class name
            [grade drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin + classNameMaxWidth + kColumnMargin, currentPageY, gradeMaxWidth, maxHeight) withFont:classFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

            currentPageY += size.height;

        }


        // increment the page number.
        currentPage++;

    }

    // end and save the PDF.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Ask the user if they'd like to see the file or email it.
    UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Would you like to preview or email this PDF?"
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                     otherButtonTitles:@"Preview", @"Email", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Can someone look at the above given information and help me change this create pdf code to read the data i am saving to the `plist` in my document directory please. here is the link to the demo project in github for anyone that wants to lend a helping hand.:)

Additional info:

I am saving the user input data in `plist` which the root is an array. the code I am using to render the `PDF` file is from a `plist` that the root is dictionary. I need help with changing the code in `pdfpressed` to read the `plist` that the root would be an array not a dictionary.

[image]

Edit:

i used the fix that was posted and the whole method looks like this now:

```
    - (IBAction)pdfPressed:(id)sender {

     NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data1.plist"];

     NSLog(@"File Path: %@", filePath);

     NSArray *students = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    // get a temprorary filename for this PDF
    filePath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    self.pdfFilePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.pdf", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] ]];

    // Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
    // This default is spelled out in the iOS documentation for UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(self.pdfFilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    // get the context reference so we can render to it.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    int currentPage = 0;

    // maximum height and width of the content on the page, byt taking margins into account.
    CGFloat maxWidth = kDefaultPageWidth - kMargin * 2;
    CGFloat maxHeight = kDefaultPageHeight - kMargin * 2;

    // we're going to cap the name of the class to using half of the horizontal page, which is why we're dividing by 2
    CGFloat classNameMaxWidth = maxWidth / 2;

    // the max width of the grade is also half, minus the margin
    CGFloat gradeMaxWidth = (maxWidth / 2) - kColumnMargin;


    // only create the fonts once since it is a somewhat expensive operation
    UIFont* studentNameFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    UIFont* classFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

    CGFloat currentPageY = 0;

    // iterate through out students, adding to the pdf each time.
    for (NSDictionary* student in students)
    {
        // every student gets their own page
        // Mark the beginning of a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);
        currentPageY = kMargin;

        // draw the student's name at the top of the page.
        NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", [student valueForKey:@"city"], [student valueForKey:@"state"],[student valueForKey:@"cityPrice"],[student valueForKey:@"cityText"]];

        CGSize size = [name sizeWithFont:studentNameFont forWidth:maxWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [name drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(kMargin, currentPageY) forWidth:maxWidth withFont:studentNameFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        currentPageY += size.height;

        // draw a one pixel line under the student's name
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, kMargin, currentPageY);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, kDefaultPageWidth - kMargin, currentPageY);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        // iterate through the list of classes and add these to the PDF.
        NSArray* classes = [student objectForKey:@"Classes"];
        for(NSDictionary* class in classes)
        {
            NSString* className = [class objectForKey:@"Name"];
            NSString* grade = [class objectForKey:@"Grade"];

            // before we render any text to the PDF, we need to measure it, so we'll know where to render the
            // next line.
            size = [className sizeWithFont:classFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(classNameMaxWidth, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

            // if the current text would render beyond the bounds of the page,
            // start a new page and render it there instead
            if (size.height + currentPageY > maxHeight) {
                // create a new page and reset the current page's Y value
                UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);
                currentPageY = kMargin;
            }

            // render the text
            [className drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin, currentPageY, classNameMaxWidth, maxHeight) withFont:classFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

            // print the grade to the right of the class name
            [grade drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin + classNameMaxWidth + kColumnMargin, currentPageY, gradeMaxWidth, maxHeight) withFont:classFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

            currentPageY += size.height;

        }
        // increment the page number.
        currentPage++;
    }

    // end and save the PDF.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Ask the user if they'd like to see the file or email it.
    UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Would you like to preview or email this PDF?"
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                     otherButtonTitles:@"Preview", @"Email", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

it does render the data but it is all drawing as the header and creates one page per item. here is the screen shot

[image]

can you help out with separating the info and make them appear in one page.

edit 1:

here is what i am trying to do:

[image]

and here is the plist structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>city</key>
        <string>asd</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>10</string>
        <key>cituPrice</key>
        <string>11</string>
        <key>cityQuantity</key>
        <string>12</string>
        <key>cityVintage</key>
        <string>13</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>city</key>
        <string>te2</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>cityPrice</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>cityQuantity</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>cityVintage</key>
        <string>4</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>city</key>
        <string>3434</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>6</string>
        <key>cityPrice</key>
        <string>7</string>
        <key>cityQuantity</key>
        <string>8</string>
        <key>cityVintage</key>
        <string>9</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>city</key>
        <string>test 1</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>20</string>
        <key>cityPrice</key>
        <string>30</string>
        <key>cityQuantity</key>
        <string>44</string>
        <key>cityVintage</key>
        <string>55</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

that is how the structure of the plist would be when it is saved in the documents.

Comment: Your demo project lack the xcode project file.

Comment: @Moxy, sorry about that. just fixed it.

Comment: can you please provide a sample screen how you want to display the in pdf file. I will try to help to achive that

Comment: @CoolMonster, i added an image of things should look like as you requested. also thanks for trying to help man.

Comment: I tried to build your project it seems to be something wrong. Can you check and re upload your project.Any how i make separate one for this and make it work with your design and data. You want to show the data in pdf as like above image right

Comment: @XCodeMonkey you are reading the plist from the document direct right then whats your problem with your existing method. I confused with your question

Comment: @CoolMonster, the current method does not read the data i am saving. it reads from the data.plist which is empty. when i save the data i create a copy and save that in documents directory in add view. i want to read the data i am adding from the copy of the plist which i add the data into. i can read that data in my tableview and show it in the detail view. i want to change the code in create pdf method to read the data i saved.

Comment: @coolMonster, fixed the link to the project and uploaded it again. should work now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49066/discussion-between-coolmonster-and-xcode-monkey)

Comment: Why pdf? may be html + UIWebView is better solution?

Comment: @Cy-4AH, can you offer a working code + solution.? I'm pretty much open at this point. you can download the project and change it to reflect your solution. i just want to be able to view the data and print and or email it. as i said, i open to any solution at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Solution**
Replace the method in pdfgenerate

```
- (IBAction)pdfPressed:(id)sender {

     NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

     NSLog(@"File Path: %@", filePath);

     NSArray *students = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    // get a temprorary filename for this PDF
    filePath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    self.pdfFilePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.pdf", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] ]];

    // Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
    // This default is spelled out in the iOS documentation for UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(self.pdfFilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    // get the context reference so we can render to it.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    int currentPage = 0;

    // maximum height and width of the content on the page, byt taking margins into account.
    CGFloat maxWidth = kDefaultPageWidth - kMargin * 2;
    CGFloat maxHeight = kDefaultPageHeight - kMargin * 2;

    // we're going to cap the name of the class to using half of the horizontal page, which is why we're dividing by 2
    CGFloat classNameMaxWidth = maxWidth / 2;

    // the max width of the grade is also half, minus the margin
    CGFloat gradeMaxWidth = (maxWidth / 2) - kColumnMargin;
    CGFloat grade1MaxWidth = (maxWidth / 2) - kColumnMargin;
    CGFloat grade2MaxWidth = (maxWidth / 2) - kColumnMargin;


    // only create the fonts once since it is a somewhat expensive operation
    UIFont* studentNameFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    UIFont* classFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

    CGFloat currentPageY = 0;
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);
    currentPageY = kMargin;
    // iterate through out students, adding to the pdf each time.
    for (NSDictionary* student in students)
    {
        // every student gets their own page
        // Mark the beginning of a new page.


        // draw the student's name at the top of the page.
        NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          [student valueForKey:@"city"]];

        CGSize HeaderSize = [name sizeWithFont:studentNameFont forWidth:maxWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


        // iterate through the list of classes and add these to the PDF.
        //NSArray* classes = [student objectForKey:@"Classes"];

            NSString* className = [student valueForKey:@"state"];
            NSString* grade = [student valueForKey:@"cityPrice"];
            NSString* grade1 = [student valueForKey:@"cityText"];
            NSString* grade2 = [student valueForKey:@"cityQuantity"];

            // before we render any text to the PDF, we need to measure it, so we'll know where to render the
            // next line.
           CGSize DetailSize = [className sizeWithFont:classFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(classNameMaxWidth, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

            // if the current text would render beyond the bounds of the page,
            // start a new page and render it there instead

        if (HeaderSize.height + DetailSize.height+currentPageY > maxHeight) {
            // create a new page and reset the current page's Y value
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);
            currentPageY = kMargin;
            currentPage++;
        }
        [name drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(kMargin, currentPageY) forWidth:maxWidth withFont:studentNameFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


        // draw a one pixel line under the student's name
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, kMargin, currentPageY+HeaderSize.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, kDefaultPageWidth - kMargin, currentPageY+HeaderSize.height);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        // render the text
        [className drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin, currentPageY+HeaderSize.height, classNameMaxWidth, maxHeight) withFont:classFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

        // print the grade to the center of the class name
        [grade drawInRect:CGRectMake (kMargin , currentPageY+HeaderSize.height, gradeMaxWidth, maxHeight) withFont:classFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        // print the grade1 to the right of the class name
        [grade1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin  , currentPageY+HeaderSize.height, grade1MaxWidth, maxHeight) withFont:classFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];

        [grade2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin  , currentPageY+HeaderSize.height, grade2MaxWidth, maxHeight) withFont:classFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
        // increment the page number.
         currentPageY = currentPageY+DetailSize.height+HeaderSize.height+30;

    }

    // end and save the PDF.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Ask the user if they'd like to see the file or email it.
    UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Would you like to preview or email this PDF?"
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                     otherButtonTitles:@"Preview", @"Email", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];





}
```

**OLD Solution**

```
   NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data1.plist"];

        NSLog(@"File Path: %@", filePath);

       NSArray *students = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

You have to get the value for specific key not an object for that key

```
[student objectForKey:@"city"];
```

Instead of the above line use it like this

```
[student valueForKey:@"city"];
```

You storing the data as Array so you can get the array of content, The above code will help you to fetch the array of object in student variable as you did in pdfpressed, the you can proceed the same to draw the content in pdf file.

[image]

Comment: brings up errors download the sample project and see. the whole idea is to display the data that the user inputs in the add view controller. and then create a pdf with that data. how would i go about doing that.

Comment: can you fork the project on github and plug in your code. i did and it shows null as the out data out put in the pdf. i believe that the code works in finding the plist in doc directory but drawing the pdf doesn't work. can you show me how to draw the info with your code?

Comment: added your fix and posted an edit on my question. can you take a look and see if there is a way we can fix that. i want to draw the info in a chart as the image in my question. i also posted a screen shot of what i am getting now.

Comment: i accepted your answer but it is basically half of what i wanted. city is just one of the strings. i have added the other strings to the view throughout the same approach and what it does is rendering them to the view but it creates one page per title. all i want is to line up the content like a list so when i create for example 100 entries they show up as a list. is there any help you can offer ?

Comment: Sure man I will help u with this, u sync the source so far u did in git. Tomorrow I will update as u expect.

Comment: can u share a sample data.plist and sample pdf file how u want to render the content. I am not clear on how u actually want, i updated my answer with a image but not sure, whether you want it like.

Comment: it looks cool. what i want is to have the items not repeat in each section. header will be the name and a line underneath and then just the values of that particular item. then another header and a line and the next items. I've updated my question with the image and the plist structure.

Comment: never mind my last comment. just added 120 to the grade2MaxWidth manually and got the value to print. i have to say that you have been amazingly helpful. please let me know if you are on twitter or Facebook so i can connect with you. here is my email if you want to stay in touch and do some projects together. i am going to up vote you in order to compensate you for the bounty which i forgot to award you. you deserve a medal dude. here is my email xcodemonkey@comcast.net please stay in touch bro.